# Make a connection through MS Access to a DB in a shared folder

Tags: linux, database, database-connection, ms-access-2007, samba

I have a `.mdb` Data Base in a folder shared through a Linux Server, using SAMBA. Also, I have a little program that requires a connection to that `.mdb` but something is failing and I can't find it where or why. I suppose it is related to Linux server, because I can Access the folder though "run prompt", `Windows + R -> \\hostname\sharedfolder`, even using IP instead the hostname.

I have this.

```
Dim CADENA as String
CADENA="\\linuxserver\sharedfolder\database.mbd"

Set dbs=New ADODB.Connection
dbs.Open"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & CADENA
```

Where do I have to check or what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

If I were in this situation I would try setting up a System DSN connecting to the Samba server and open the connection through that.  My (educated) guess is you're missing authentication information or something for that connection.

Separating the DSN from your code would allow you to debug the two of them separately, which seems to be necessary because you are not posting an error message.